# Autoscaling Groups: what happens during scale-in if all ec2 are termination protected?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

Suppose I create an ec2 autoscaling group where each instance is protect terminated.
Suppose a min of 2 and a maximum of 4, I was wondering what happens if, in presence of a step policy:

1. There is a scale-out of 4 and then a scale-in: will always 4 instances be present? Or only 2 will be in the autoscaling group while the others are "benched" somewhat
2. There is scale-out again: will the extra 2 instance be used or other 2 will be created?

Comment: Don't turn termination protection on for auto-scaled instances. If you want to know what happens you can probably set this up in an hour to test, and it might cost you a few dollars at most and you'd learn a lot doing it - let us know what you find :)

Comment: Actually termination protection is useful if you have a mixed types of instances and you want to avoid one specific type to be terminated....

Comment: Why would you want mixed instance types in your target group? There are some valid reasons, but in most cases similar instance sizes are simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If all ec2 instances in an Auto Scaling group are protected from termination during scale in, and a scale-in
event occurs, its desired capacity is decremented.

The Auto Scaling group can't terminate the required number of instances until their instance scale-in protection settings are disabled.